# Unable to update ubuntu Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS. Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, update-manager

I am unable to update my Ubuntu repositories. The command apt-get update gives following error

```
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-aarch64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/hugin/hugin-builds/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-aarch64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/dists/stable/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'non-free/binary-aarch64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian/dists/jessie/InRelease Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-aarch64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-aarch64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-aarch64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead
```

I even replaced my sources.list file with the one I generated using **Ubuntu Sources List Generator**.
This is my **sources.list** file.

```
###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main universe multiverse  
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main universe multiverse 

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main universe multiverse
```

Comment: Are you really running an aarch64 system?

Comment: no it is x86_64.

Comment: Read the Warning messages carefully. They tell you exactly what the problem is. It's the same problem on each line.